# Matching Records at database level

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Ruby on rails 5 and I have a table called `Transaction(reference,id)`. This table has `nth transactions` but at each point, at most 2 transactions have the same `reference number` but different `ids`. How do I match or reconcile the two `transactions` with matching reference or pair them in one select row at the database level?(tried using loops, was too slow for large transactions). Using postgresql

Answer (score 1):

Use group by

```
Transaction.group_by(&:reference).each do |reference, transaction|
  p "#{reference} -> #{transaction.map(&:class).join(', ')}"
end

output like this 
"#reference number -> Transaction"
"#reference number -> Transaction"
"#reference number -> Transaction, Transaction"
```

Try this

Comment: what does the class stand for?

Comment: its object class name.